# Evince slow start with "nimf" installed

Tags: release-loki, input

## PREREQUISITES

- `nimf` is a software input method like `ibus`.
- Evince is the default document viewer in eOS.

---

I have installed `nimf` recently then noticed that Evince is not starting as quick as usual (delayed start for about 15 seconds with 0 CPU use). I have run it on the terminal to see what was going on, then found some log messages that are seemingly associated with `nimf`. I have removed `nimf` entirely from my computer, and it worked just fine.

I prefer `nimf` over `ibus` because it *just works* once you install, unlike `ibus` that I have had to figure out this and that to get it working. However, given that Evince is one of the most beautiful apps in eOS and better than Adobe Reader (for being snappy and lightweight + touchscreen support) and Chrome's built-in reader (for not being a CPU hog on my HiDPI display), not being able to use both together at the same time is pretty frustrating.

Has this bug filed already? Should I file one now? How can I get both of them working together?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug with evince in Ubuntu with Debian.
This is the report of nimf developer against evince in launchpad.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1569863
I think evince team should reply to report to fix this issue.
Alternative Input Method is uim-byeoru, It has no issue in Loki.

```
sudo apt install uim uim-byeoru
im-config -n uim
```

and This is for settings

```
uim-pref-gtk
```

or find "uim" in slingshot after logout & login, I hope it might help you https://youtu.be/q9QntqhecSk :)